# Searching Item ArrayList by Property

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Objects/Items with 3 properties, Priority #, Description, and Reference #. The program is suppose to allow you to print the Item from Arraylist based on the item's reference #. For some reason the compiler won't let me iterate through the ArrayList to find the matching item.
The part I'm stuck on (inside the method 'findbyrefer'):

```
for(Object list : list.getMyList()){
                if(list.getReference.equals(num)){
                    System.out.println(list);
                }
```

My main:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner myscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean exit = false;
    boolean error = false;
    boolean error1 = false;

    String input = "";
    int num = 0;
    System.out.println("Welcome to Your To-Do List!\n1 = Create New Item \n2 = Exit \n3 = Display Item \n4 = Delete Item");

    while(exit == false){
    Item item = new Item();
    do{
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter a command ");
            input = myscanner.nextLine();
            num = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if(num ==  1){
                item.reference();
                System.out.println("Reference: "+ item.getReference() + "\nDescription: " + item.getDescription() + "\nPriority: " + item.getPriority());
                error = true;
            }
            /**
             * This creates the item
             */
            else if(num == 2){
                exit = true;
                System.out.println("Bye"); break;
            }
            else if(num == 3){
                item.findbyrefer();
                /**
                 * This is the part I'm stuck at
                 */
            }
            else{
                error = true;
                System.out.println("invalid");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("invalid input");
            error = true;
        }
    }
    while(error);   
    }
}
```

My Item Class:

```
 public class Item {
private Scanner myScanner;
private int reference;
private String description;
private int priority;
List list = new List();

public void setReference(int reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
}
public int getReference() {
    return reference;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public String getDescription() {
}
public void setPriority(int priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}
public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public void reference(){
    boolean error = false;
    int x = 0;
    do{
        try{
            System.out.println("Assign this item with a reference number: ");
            myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            x=myScanner.nextInt();
            setReference(x);
            error=false;
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            error = true;
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }
    } while(error);
    description();
}

public void description(){
    boolean error = true;
    while(error){
        try{
            System.out.println("Enter the description: ");
            myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = myScanner.nextLine();
            setDescription(input);
            error=false;
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            error = true;
            System.out.println("invalid");
            break;
        }
    }
    priority();
}

public void priority(){
    boolean error = false;
    do{
        try{
            System.out.println("Assign this item with a priority number: ");
            myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            setPriority(myScanner.nextInt());
            error=false;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            error = true;
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }
    }
    while(error==true);
    list.addItem(this);
    System.out.println(list.getMyList());
}
public void findbyrefer(){
    boolean error1 = false;
    String input = "";
    int num = 0;
    do{
        try{
            System.out.println("Enter the reference number of the item you want to show");
            myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            input = myScanner.nextLine();
            num = Integer.parseInt(input);
            for(Object list : list.getMyList()){
                if(list.equals(num)){
                    System.out.println(list);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("not working");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            error1 = true;
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }
    }
    while(error1 = true);
}
```

}
My List Class that contains my actual ArrayList:

```
public class List {
public ArrayList<Object> MyList = new ArrayList<Object>();

public void setMyList(ArrayList<Object> myList) {
    this.MyList = myList;
}
public ArrayList<Object> getMyList() {
    return MyList;
}

public void addItem (Object t){
    getMyList().add(t);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add () parenthesis for getReference method of list and use (==) equal operator.

```
 for(Object list : list.getMyList()){
         if(list.getReference() == num)){
            System.out.println(list);
         }
}
```

Comment: That's *one* of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getReference` method on `Object`.

Since your ArrayList contains `Item`s, let it know that:

```
ArrayList<Item> myList = new ArrayList<>();
// ------^^^^^^
```

Now looking at your loop:

```
for(Object list : list.getMyList()){
    if(list.getReference.equals(num)){
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

We need to:

1. Change `Object` to `Item`
2. Use a different identifier than `list` for the items (just to avoid confusion)
3. *Call* `getReference` (add `()`)
4. Use `==`, not `equals`, to check `num` (`equals` is for objects)

So:

```
for (Item item : list.getMyList()) {
    if (item.getReference() == num){
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is to get you started. There are bound to be other follow-on issues, a thorough code audit is off-topic for SO. But if you run into further problems, read the error messages carefully, do research, check Java books and tutorials, etc. If you get *really* stuck, post a new question about the specific thing you're stuck on with a [mcve] (note the "Minimal") demonstrating that specific problem.